How to attach a child diagram stereotype to a custom Stereotype
We are creating a set of custom stereotypes. What we would like to achieve is:
When an element is created based on a Custom Stereotype (by dragging it from the Toolbox onto a Diagram), the resulting Element has a child diagram of a certain type, present in our Diagram Profile
We've tried adding a composite diagram (a diagram from our diagram profile) as a child diagram to the custom stereotype. This, however does not seem to work.

What you need are the settings Default Diagram Type and Make Composite
Make Composite automatically creates a composite diagram when you create a new element of your stereotype.
The Default Diagram Type indicates which diagram that should be.

In this example that's a diagram defined in my own MDG with the fully qualified name KPI::KPI & Reporting Diagram

Great. This works.

@RikvanderSchalie if this answers your question you can mark the answer as "Accepted" using the checkmark on the the left of the answer.

I now run into the following: this solution appears to apply to all Stereotypes in our MDG, defined on the Metaclass "Class" (I had to select "Class" in the "Extensions:" box to have the fields appear in the Metaclass dialog where I could enter the Default Diagram Type, and the Make Composite fields). I wanted this to apply to just one custom Stereotype, and not all of them.

Each stereotype should extend it's own metaclass. You shouldn't re-use metaclasses

Yes, that fixes it.
